# Unordered List wrap using display: inline-block

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I'm working on project where I have to simulate an input in HTML and CSS. Inside the input I should be able to call a function like: `my_cool_function(param0, param1, param2, param3)`. So to simulate the input I created a unordered list and inside the ul I'm adding the function as a token. So my_cool_function(param0, param1, param2, param3) itself is a complete token. But `param0`, `param1` `etcetera` are also tokens. So this is the current html structure I have:

```
<ul class="list">
    <li class="token">
        <span>My_cool_Function</span>
        <ul class="tokenparams">
            <li class="token">
                <span>Param0</span>
            </li>
            <li class="token">
                <span>Param1</span></li>
            <li class="token">
                <span>Param2</span>
            </li>
            <li class="token">
                <span>Param3</span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And this works provided that the width of the ul allows to the whole function to fit. So when the width is lower it kind of breaks and I want it to wrap nicely. This is the css:

```
ul.list{
    height: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 600px;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.428571429;
    color: #555;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    cursor: text;
}

li.token{
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    margin: 0 10px 0 0;
    padding: 0 1px 0 1px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    height: 18px;
    vertical-align: top;
    cursor: pointer;
}

li.token span {
    float:left;
}

li.active {
    border-color: #63B9FF;
}

ul.tokenparams {
    list-style-type: none;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 0;
}

ul.tokenparams::before {
    content: "(";
    float: left;
    margin-left: 2px;
}

ul.tokenparams::after {
    content: ")";
    margin-right: 2px;
}

ul.tokenparams .token:not(:last-child)::after{
    content: ",";
}
```

So at 600px of width it looks like this:

[image: example at 600px]

And at 355px this happens:

[image: example at 350px]

This is a fiddle showing the error: http://jsfiddle.net/jvxzLt2s/

I would like to create like a new line and break it on `param2` and `param3` in a new line.

Comment: Can you show the expected output image?

Comment: it doesnt wrap for me.

Answer (score 0):

Is this something like what you want?

http://jsfiddle.net/joe_young/jvxzLt2s/3/

I've just taken out the `height`s

```
ul.list{
    /* Removed 'height: auto;' here */
    display: block;
    width: 350px;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.428571429;
    color: #555;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    cursor: text;
}

input.input{
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 12px;
    background-color: white;
    -webkit-appearance: caret;
}

li.token{
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    margin: 0 10px 0 0;
    padding: 0 1px 0 1px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    /* Removed 'height: 18px;' here */
    vertical-align: top;
    cursor: pointer;
}

li.token span {
    float:left;
}

li.active {
    border-color: #63B9FF;
}

ul.tokenparams {
    list-style-type: none;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 0;
}

ul.tokenparams::before {
    content: "(";
    float: left;
    margin-left: 2px;
}

ul.tokenparams::after {
    content: ")";
    margin-right: 2px;
}

ul.tokenparams .token:not(:last-child)::after{
    content: ",";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will have the ul.tokenparams li.tokens wrap individually.

http://jsfiddle.net/8ee3asjf/

```
 ul.list{
    height: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.428571429;
    color: #555;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    cursor: text;
}

input.input{
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 12px;
    background-color: white;
    -webkit-appearance: caret;
}

li.token{
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    margin: 0 10px 0 0;
    padding: 0 1px 0 1px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    height: 18px;
    vertical-align: top;
    cursor: pointer;
}
ul > li{float:left;}
li.token span {
    float:left;
}

li.active {
    border-color: #63B9FF;
}

ul.tokenparams {
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    display:inline;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-left: 0;
    width:auto;

}

ul.tokenparams::before {
    content: "(";
    float: left;
    margin-left: 2px;
}

ul.tokenparams::after {
    content: ")";
    margin-right: 2px;
    float:left;
}

ul.tokenparams .token:not(:last-child)::after{
    content: ",";

}
```